# what can be the proper way of strategies implementation in a trading client?

Tags: c++, algorithmic-trading

This question requires some knowledge of algorithmic trading and IB TWS API.

I am currently considering how to implement the notion of many strategies that
may trade simultaneously. I wonder if I should even host them all in a single
client - or maybe use 1 client-1 algo approach. If I choose many strategies
running in parallel in my one and only client (this might be beneficial) what
pattern is a best choice?

At the moment I am thinking about something like this:

```
1. GUI: I have i.e. buttons:
STRATEGY 1 -> start,stop,view status/details, etc.
STRATEGY 2 -> start,stop,view status/details, etc.
STRATEGY 3 -> start,stop,view status/details, etc.
```

each strategy is a class that implements some basic concepts

```
class Strategy{ // Template method approach
public:
    void start(); // uses subscribeData(), trade()
private:
    virtual void subscribeData();
    virtual void trade();
    boost::shared_ptr<Model> model;
    boost::shared_ptr<Data> data;
    boost::shared_ptr<Statistics> stats;
};
```

So the real, most important part will end then in a `trade()` method, and all
strategy classes operate on same single instance of my `PosixClient`
implementation of IB `EWrapper` with `EPosixClientSocket` pointer in it (so one
socket).

Is this correct approach? I have experience with risk management systems (Algorithmics i.e.) but haven't seen any commercial trading system implementation. Can you give some advice?

Answer (score 0):

Very good question.

I would recommend developing every strategy in its own module / client / JVM.

Have a look at the Algorithmic Trading Framework AlgoTrader.

This framework allows you develop / deploy / start / stop / update Strategies independent from each other in separate JVMs. They all sit on top of what is called the Base, which is responsible for Market Data Connections, Persistence to the database and placing orders with the Broker. Different modules / strategies can even communicate with each other through generic events.

There are two versions available of AlgoTrader.

- An Open Source Version that you can download for free from [here](http://code.google.com/p/algo-trader/)
- A Commercial Version (with Support and Professional Services) is available [here](http://www.algotrader.ch)

Comment: many thanks, and thank you for a link - I will investigate, however: why should I download this? Frankly, this was the reason why I started to programming because I am not satisfied with all these "solutions" and I want to implement my own ideas, my own concepts, using my own imagination and knowledge. And this is why I ask for advice, this doesn't mean that I will do it necessarily like others do, but just want to gather a broad picture  ; d